# Summation of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

So consider a summation of ai cos (x + phi_i) where i ranges from 1 to N. Could we describe this summation as a single cosine function? Or the sum of two cosine or sine functions? How would we do this and what would be the amplitude of the cosine function in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Each $\cos(x+\phi_i)$ breaks into a multiple of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, so the sum can be re-written as:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N a_i \cos(x+\phi_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^N a_i\left(\cos x \cos\phi_i - \sin x\sin \phi_i \right) \\
&= \cos x \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \cos\phi_i - \sin x \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \sin \phi_i \\
&=: p \cos x - q \sin x
\end{align}$$

So, the answer to the question "Could we describe this summation as [...] the sum of a sine and cosine function [of $x$]?" is: YES!

Now, it would be awfully convenient if you could think of $p$ and $q$ as (a multiple of) the cosine and sine of an angle, because then you could use the angle addition formula to collapse the terms. That is, if ...
$$p = r \cos \theta \qquad q = r \sin \theta \qquad \qquad (1)$$
... then ...
$$p \cos x - q \sin x = r \cos x \cos \theta - r \sin x \sin\theta = r \left( \cos x \cos\theta - \sin x \sin\theta \right) = r \cos(x+\theta)$$
In that case, the answer to the question "Could we describe this summation as a single cosine function?" is also: YES! ... provided we can find the appropriate $r$ and $\theta$ to satisfy $(1)$. But that's easy when you think about how those values have to work.

---

Since $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$, equation $(1)$ requires that
$$p^2 + q^2 = r^2 \cos^2\theta + r^2 \sin^2\theta = r^2 (1) = r^2$$
Therefore, if $r$ is to be *anything*, it has to be 
$$r = \pm \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$$
Since we just need *some* $r$, we can go ahead and take the "$\pm$" to be "$+$".

This answers the question "[W]hat would be the amplitude of the cosine function [...]?"

---

Moreover, since $\sin/\cos = \tan$, equation $(1)$ also requires that
$$\frac{q}{p} = \frac{r \sin\theta}{r \cos\theta} = \tan\theta$$
so that, if $\theta$ is going to be *anything*, it has to be
$$\theta = \operatorname{atan}\frac{q}{p} + k \pi \quad\text{for some integer}\quad k$$ 
And since we just need *some* $\theta$, we can go ahead and take $k$ to be $0$.

Although you didn't ask for it, this gives you the phase shift of the cosine function.

---

The relation 
$$p \cos x - q \sin x = r \cos \left(x + \theta\right)$$
can be illustrated nicely with a diagram:

[image]

Comment: very nice diagram